# Missing required parameter for [Route: tasks.update] [URI: tasks/{task}] [Missing parameter: task]

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8, crud

I am using laravel 8 for an edit operation for which I have created Resource controller by using php artisan command and create has worked perfectly but edit operation is not working correctly giving error as 'Missing required parameter for [Route: tasks.update] [URI: tasks/{task}] [Missing parameter: task]'

web.php

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use App\Http\Controllers\TaskController;

Route::resource('tasks', TaskController::class);
```

list.blade.php

```
<table class="table table-bordered">
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th>Title</th>
    <th>Assigned User</th>
    <th>Status</th>
    <th>Action</th>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    @if(count($tasks)>0)
        @foreach($tasks AS $record)
            <tr>
              <td>{{ $record->title }}</td>
              <td>{{ $record->name }}</td>
              <td>{{ $record->status }}</td>
              <td> <a href="{{ route('tasks.edit', $record->id) }}"> Edit </a> | <a href="{{ route('tasks.delete', $record->id) }}"> Delete </a> </td>
            </tr>
        @endforeach
    @else
        <tr><td colspan="3" align="center">No Records Found.</td></tr>
    @endif
 </tbody>
</table>
```

edit.blade.php

```
<form name="" action="{{ route('tasks.update', $record->id) }}" method="POST">
@csrf
@method('PUT')
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="title">Title: </label>
    <input type="text" name="title" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Title" value="{{ $record->title }}">
    <span class="text-danger">@error('title') {{ $message }} @enderror</span>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="password">Assign to User: </label>
    <select class="form-control" name="assigned_user_id">
        <option value="">--Select User--</option>
        @foreach($users as $each_user)
            <option value="{{ $each_user->id }}" {{ ($each_user->id == $record->assigned_user_id) ? 'selected' : '' }} >{{ $each_user->name }}</option>
        @endforeach
    </select>
    <span class="text-danger">@error('assigned_user_id') {{ $message }} @enderror</span>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="password">Task Status: </label>
    <select class="form-control" name="task_status_id">
        <option value="">--Select Status--</option>
        @foreach($task_status as $each_status)
            <option value="{{ $each_status->id }}" {{ ($each_status->id == $record->task_status_id) ? 'selected' : '' }} >{{ $each_status->status }}</option>
        @endforeach
    </select>
    <span class="text-danger">@error('task_status_id') {{ $message }} @enderror</span>
    </div>
   <div class="form-group">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-block btn-primary">Update</button>
 </div>
 <br>
</form>
```

TaskController.php

```
public function edit(Task $id)
{
    // echo $id;exit;
    $task = Task::find($id);
    $users = DB::table('users')->get();
    $task_status = DB::table('task_status')->get();
    // dd($task);
    return view('tasks.edit',['record'=>$task,'users'=>$users, 'task_status'=>$task_status]);
}
public function update(Request $request,Task $id)
{
   
}
```

Any help, Thanks.

Comment: You need to pass the `ID` (task primary key in this case) by initializing the parameter from your blade route action. [Official documentation on resource routes](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/controllers#actions-handled-by-resource-controller). You may pass your parameters with `{{ route('tasks.edit', ['task' => $record->id]}}` and same way for the update route as well.

Comment: Maybe try [checking the routing docs](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#generating-urls-to-named-routes)?

Answer (score 3):

In your form change this

```
action="{{ route('tasks.update', $record->id)
```

to

```
action="{{ route('tasks.update', ['task' => $record->id])
```

and an advice:

[Laravel Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#implicit-binding):

> Laravel automatically resolves Eloquent models defined in routes or controller actions whose type-hinted variable names match a route segment name.

In your code you should change this

```
public function edit(Task $id)
{
    $task = Task::find($id);
    $users = DB::table('users')->get();
    $task_status = DB::table('task_status')->get();
    return view('tasks.edit',['record'=>$task,'users'=>$users, 'task_status'=>$task_status]);
}
```

to

```
public function edit(Task $task) 
{
    //$task = Task::find($id); Task is already loaded (($id ==> $task))
    $users = DB::table('users')->get();
    $task_status = DB::table('task_status')->get();
    return view('tasks.edit',['record'=>$task,'users'=>$users, 'task_status'=>$task_status]);
}
```

And if you don't want to bind the model, remove "Task" from parameters.

Comment: Though it is good advice, the type-hinting suggestion is nothing to do with OP's actual error. The `route()` update is all that is required to fix their error.

Comment: @Don'tPanic hmm you're right.. I updated the answer.

Comment: @CornelRaiu As my first comment says, OP's error has nothing to do with type-hinting.  The resource route names the parameter `{task}`, so the `route()` helper expects a `task`, as the error msg confirms: "*Missing parameter: task*".  What happens in the controller is a later step, and not related.  @Reundo's answer is correct, and the extra advice they gave will get type-hinting working as well.

Comment: @Reundo Thank you for the answer but it dint work.

Comment: @PrasadPatel if you didn't change the parameter's name then use `action="{{ route('tasks.update', ['id' => $record->id])`

Comment: @Reundo No I have tried by changing the parameters name to `public function edit(Task $task)` but still it dint work.